Copy live wordpress site to local server does not work
I am trying to duplicate a live wordpress site to my windows 10 pc.
I use Wamp.
I exported and imported the database.
I can browse the tables in the database.
I copied all the files from public_html into:
c:\wamp64\www\mysite.local
I changed the database details in wp_config to:
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

I added this in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:
127.0.0.1 mysite.local
::1 mysite.local

I added this in C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.51\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.local
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/mysite.local"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/mysite.local">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

When I browse localhost I see the folder under: VirtualHost.
Clicking on mysite.local it opens a save file window with random letters as the file name, every time different letters, instead of showing me the site.
What am I missing?

You have to change siteurl and homeurl options accordingly in the table wp_option of your Wordpress database.
Basically you have to to enable URL writing, Open the httpd.conf file and search rewrite and remove # at the starting of the line,so the line will look like. LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so and restart the wamp.
And
click: WAMP icon -> Apache -> Apache modules -> chose rewrite_module
and do restart for all services.
and you have add an .htaccess file in you root directory.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ 
</IfModule>

You could try either WAMP or XAMPP, which are both supported on Windows.

Thank you very much. My WAMP is already set with rewriteModule on and everything you mentioned. I did change the siteurl and homeurl in the wp_option table.
The htaccess file has this in it:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml

